# open and close windows console from python

Tags: python, windows, cmd, pip

I am trying to write a script to open the windows console, then install a python package with pip and finally close.

This was my initial try

```
import os
os.system('pip install package')
```

The installations fails. It seems I need to open first the console and then pip, to make it work so 2nd try

```
import os
os.system('cmd.exe')
os.system('pip install package')
```

If I do it in this way it is waiting until the console is closed to execute pip

3rd try

```
import os
os.system('cmd.exe')
os.system('exit')
os.system('pip install package')
```

Exit is not recognised

```
I tried also with 
os.system('taskkill cmd.exe')
```

or

```
import sys
sys.exit()
```

or

```
raise SystemExit
```

No success so far

Comment: `os.system('C:\Python\Python35-32\Scripts\pip install package')` - give path to pip on your system

Answer (score 2):

pip is a package. This means you can do `import pip` and run the python function directly. A quick look using `help(pip)` shows there is a `pip.commands` package which provides `install` which looks promising.

You cannot run multiple system commands as your earlier examples. Each such command will run in a separate subprocess. Most likely `os.system("cmd /c pip install package")` might have worked as that runs a cmd shell and passes a command to it to be run. I'd expect to have to pass the full path to the pip executable though.

Comment: `os.system` already runs using `cmd /c`. But you don't need the cmd shell. It works with `subprocess.call` without `shell=True`. pip.exe opens its own console window (that's conhost.exe, not cmd.exe) if it doesn't inherit one. When pip exits, so does conhost if no other program has attached to it.